# Disable Mouse Click and Mouse Over in WKWebView

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, wkwebview, nsview

I'm new, bear with me. Xcode on MacOS (not iOS) using WKWebView / NSView /NSWindow to embed a youtube video:

```
@property (assign) IBOutlet NSView *webNSView;
@property (assign) IBOutlet WKWebView *webView;

- (void)windowDidLoad {
WKWebView *webView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.webNSView.frame];
webView.navigationDelegate = self;
NSURL *nsurl=[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.youtube.com/embed/C0DPdy98e4c"];
NSURLRequest *nsrequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:nsurl];
[webView loadRequest:nsrequest];
[self.webNSView addSubview:webView]; }
```

How can I disable all mouse interaction in the window so the user can't interact with the video or init mouseovers in the WKWebView. So I am looking to disable mouse click and the mouse-over actions on the window / view. I have tried various embed options with youtube but I think it needs to be done on the window/view.

Comment: Just a nitpick - learn couple of things: 1) Spelling `XCode` -> `Xcode`, `MacOS` -> `macOS`, ... 2) [Markdown Editing Help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) - content of the `viewDidLoad` is not indented, ... 3) There's no need to include Xcode, macOS, ... in the question title, tags are enough 4) Don't overuse tags like `xcode`, read [info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xcode/info) to learn when you should use them, ...  These things are just my observations after reading couple of your questions and they do show if one cares or not (IMHO).

Comment: Thank you for your advice I am very new to coding and stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you really want is to disable all interaction with the window, you can set the `ignoresMouseEvent` property to `YES`. You can do this via a `NSWindow` or `NSWindowController` subclass:

```
@interface MyWindowController : NSWindowController
@end

@implementation MyWindowController

- (void)windowDidLoad {
    self.window.ignoresMouseEvents = YES;
}

@end
```

Be aware that this really disables ALL mouse interaction with the window, including the title bar. You usually want something a little less agressive.

An alternative would be to subclass the `WKWebView` and override the mouse events handling methods inherited from the `NSResponder` class.

```
@interface MyWebView : WKWebView
@end

@implementation MyWebView

- (void)mouseUp:(NSEvent *)event {}
- (void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)event {}
- (void)mouseMoved:(NSEvent *)event {}
- (void)mouseEntered:(NSEvent *)event {}
- (void)mouseExited:(NSEvent *)event {}

@end
```

Those events will be swallowed and won't be propagated through the event handling mechanism.